how c++ update folder&files last modify time in windows (linux works)
I wrote a program to copy the directory tree and the result will same as the source, including the last modification time.
They're both compiler successes
In Linux, the program can run as expected.
In Windows, it fails because directory cannot be set time and File exists, but in Linux did not happen (file if exists, will overwrite and time would be updated)
I've tried to run it as admin(CMD/PowerShell), and that's still getting the same errors.
how can I fix it?
Thanks all.
env

Linux ubuntu 22.04 LTS, g++/gcc 11.4.0
windows 11, g++/gcc 13.1.0

compile

g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -o main (Linux)
g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -o main.exe (windows)

windows error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot set file time: Permission denied [D:\to\working\path\output\test_folder]

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot copy file: File exists [D:\to\working\path\src\test_folder\a1.txt] [D:\to\working\path\output\test_folder\a1.txt]

my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = filesystem;

void copy_directory(const fs::path& src, const fs::path& dst) {
    // directory create
    if (!fs::exists(dst))
        fs::create_directories(dst);

    // directory walk
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(src)) {
        const auto& entry_path = entry.path();
        const auto& file_name = entry_path.filename();
        const auto& dst_file_path = dst / file_name;

        if (fs::is_directory(entry_path)) {
            copy_directory(entry_path, dst_file_path);
        }
        else if (fs::is_regular_file(entry_path)) {
            // files update time to last modification
            auto modify_time = fs::last_write_time(entry_path);
            fs::copy_file(entry_path, dst_file_path, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
            fs::last_write_time(dst_file_path, modify_time);
        }
    }

    // folder update time to last modification
    auto modify_time = fs::last_write_time(src);
    fs::last_write_time(dst, modify_time);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto src = argv[1];
    auto dst = fs::current_path() / "output";
    cout << "current_path : " << fs::current_path() << endl;
    cout << "src : " << src << endl;
    cout << "dst : " << dst << endl;

    copy_directory(src, dst);
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    cout << "Time spent: " << duration.count() / 1000000.0 << " seconds" << endl;
    return 0;
}


Sounds like you're trying to do something the windows filesystem doesn't allow.

Yes, I was wondering do I need to change to another library to copy.

Can you change the timestamp on a directory using powershell commands?

Yes, it can use PowerShell command
